# Using methods from a subclass on an object that is an instance of the superclass

Tags: java, inheritance

Let's say there's a class that I use extensively and is returned by a method.

```
CommonClass obj = getCommonObject();
```

Now I want to extend this class to create some utility method to avoid repeating myself.

```
public CommonClassPlus extends CommonClass {

    public String dontRepeatYourself() {
        // the reason I'm creating a subclass
    }
}
```

Of course I would like to use my improved class for the method above, however, downcasting isn't allowed.

```
CommonClassPlus obj = getCommonObject(); 
//Cannot cast to CommonClassPlus
```

How can I use the method `dontRepeatYourself()` if I can only work with the object that is an instance of the superclass?

`CommonClass` and `getCommonObject()` are from an external library and I cannot change them.

Comment: pls show the implemenation / declaration of getCommonObject().

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `CommonClass` is from an external library, you probably want to wrap it in an [Adapter Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adapter_pattern) anyway, using the principle of [Composition over Inheritance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance).

This gives you complete control if you want to, say, change the library you're using, and allows you to add functionality like `dontRepeatYourself()`.

```
public class CommonClassAdapter implements MyAdapter {
    private final CommonClass common;
    private final String cachedResult;

    // Note that I'm doing dependency injection here
    public CommonClassAdapter(CommonClass common) {
        this.common = common;

        // Don't expose these because they shouldn't be called more than once
        common.methodIOnlyCallOnce();
        cachedResult = common.anotherMethodIOnlyCallOnce();
    }

    @Override
    public void someMethod() {
        common.someMethodWithDifferentName();
    }

    @Override
    public String dontRepeatYourself() {
        return cachedResult;
    }
}
```

Note also that most modern IDEs have things like Eclipse's [`Source -> Generate Delegate Methods`](http://help.eclipse.org/luna/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.user%2Freference%2Fref-menu-source.htm) to make this process faster.

Comment: I am marking this as correct because it answers the question with a good solution even though I ended up using the simpler one suggested below.

Comment: @user2730785 I agree that the other answer is much faster to implement in existing code. However I think you'll be happier in the long run with this answer.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot add behavior to an existing instance in Java (like you could in JavaScript, for example).

The closest you can get in Java is the *Decorator* pattern:

```
CommonClassPlus obj = decorate(getCommonObject());
```

where `decorate()` is

```
public CommonClassPlus decorate(CommonClass x) {
  return new CommonClassPlus(x);
}
```

This approach creates a potentially huge amount of boilerplate because it must delegate each method call to the wrapped instance. If a method in `CommonClass` is final and there is no interface you can reimplement, then this approach fails altogether.

In most cases you will be able to get along with a simple static helper method:

```
public static String dontRepeatYourself(CommonClass x) {
   ...
}
```

Comment: Using a static method actually solves the problem. Much easier thanks.